# My modelformset saves only the first generated form and doesn't add the rest

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have up to 4-5 forms, the formsets come in last, I used to javascript to generate more forms at the click of a button. After submission and validation, only the first form data gets saved to the database, the others don't, how can i fix this please?

This is my views.py file

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def addItem(request, id) -> render:
    res_name = Restro.objects.get(user=request.user)
    menuobj = Main.objects.get(restro_name=res_name)

    sub_form = createSubCartForm(request.POST)
    itemformset = modelformset_factory(Item, form=addItemForm, extra=0, fields=['itname', 'quantity'])
    itemform = itemformset(request.POST or None)
    
    vsub_form = createVSubCartForm(request.POST)
    vitemformset = modelformset_factory(v_Item, form=addVItemForm, extra=0, fields=['vname'])
    vitemform = vitemformset(request.POST or None)
    vformset = modelformset_factory(ItemVariation, form=addItemVariationForm, extra=0, fields=['iname', 'varprice', 'quantity'])
    vform = vformset(request.POST or None)

    if 'nonala' in request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('cate1') == 'Non-Ala Carte':
            if all([sub_form.is_valid(), itemform.is_valid()]):
                global pare
                pare = sub_form.save(commit=False)
                pare.main_category = Main.objects.get(restro_name=res_name)
                pare.save()
                for form in itemform:
                    child = form.save(commit=False)
                    child.user = request.user
                    child.sub_category = Sub.objects.get(id=pare.id)
                    child.save()
                    return redirect('cust')
    elif 'ala' in request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('cate2') == 'Ala Carte':
                print(request.POST)            
    context = {
        'm_name': menuobj.main_category,
        'sub_form': sub_form,
        'itemform': itemform,
        'vsub_form': vsub_form,
        'vitemform': vitemform,
        'vform': vform
        }
    return render(request, 'item_form.html', context)
```

This is my templates file

```
<form id="non-alacart" action="" method="post" class="hidden">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h3 class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;">Create Sub Cartegory for <span id="mn">{{ m_name }}</span> Category</h3>
            <input type="text" name="cate1" id="main_ca" readonly="readonly">
            <div id="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-form-label text-center">Sub Category Name<br/>{{sub_form.sname}}</label>
                    <label class="col-form-label text-center">Sub Category Price<br/>{{sub_form.sprice}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="col-form-label text-center">Items<br>
                        <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-light link-success border rounded border-success" id="add" type="button" style="width: 119.5px;">
                            <i class="la la-plus" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);"></i>&nbsp;Add Item
                        </button>
                    </label>
                </div>
                {% if itemform %}
                {{ itemform.management_form }}
                <div id='item-list' class="row">
                    {% for form in itemform %}
                        <div class="item-form">
                            {{form}}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div id="emp-form" class="hidden">{{ itemform.empty_form }}</div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="col d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-center">
                        <button id="nal" class="btn btn-success link-light border rounded border-success" type="submit" name="nonala" style="width: 119.5px;">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and the script for generating more forms

```
const addfield = document.getElementById('add');
        const totalnewforms = document.getElementById('id_form-TOTAL_FORMS')

        addfield.addEventListener('click', additem);
        function additem(event){
            if (event){
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            const itemformno = document.getElementsByClassName('item-form')
            const itemformcount = itemformno.length//+1
            const emp_form_list = document.getElementById('item-list')
            const emp_form = document.getElementById('emp-form').cloneNode(true)
            emp_form.setAttribute('class', 'item-form row')
            emp_form.setAttribute('id', `form-${itemformcount}`)
            var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
                p[i].setAttribute('class', 'col');
            };
            const regex = new RegExp('__prefix__', 'g')
            emp_form.innerHTML = emp_form.innerHTML.replace(regex, itemformcount)
            emp_form_list.append(emp_form)
            totalnewforms.setAttribute('value', itemformcount+1)
        }
```

for example:
I generated 4 forms and submitted. This is the POST request from the form

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FDTYD9gjxr7rQP4truJIkMbcEep0cqNud4meZPDXvQQa2k8vvEZVGo9l7eJHJgVQ'], 'cate1': ['Non-Ala Carte'], 'sname': ['Pizza'], 'sprice': ['3600'], 'form-TOTAL_FORMS': ['4'], 'form-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'form-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 'form-0-itname': ['cheese'], 'form-0-quantity': ['6g'], 'form-0-id': ['3'], 'form-1-itname': ['thali'], 'form-1-quantity': ['3g'], 'form-1-id': [''], 'form-2-itname': ['brocoli'], 'form-2-quantity': ['16mg'], 'form-2-id': [''], 'form-3-itname': ['pizza'], 'form-3-quantity': ['1slice'], 'form-3-id': [''], 'form-__prefix__-itname': [''], 'form-__prefix__-quantity': [''], 'form-__prefix__-id': [''], 'nonala': ['']}>
```

it's reading getting all the form data successfully but when I call save(), only form-0 saves to the database, and after that I can't add any more details, every added one overwites the previously stored details.

Comment: Are you getting redirected to the URL "reverse('cust')" and only first sub form of "itemForm" is saved?  Try putting "return redirect('cust')" this outside for loop in your views. Looks like it is redirecting after the first child of "itemform" got saved.

Comment: I tried this and all forms finally added It worked, thanks.